# How to use datagridviewimage column to edit a specific column

Tags: c#

How to use datagridviewimage column to edit a specific column.

My purpose in using datagridviewimage is for increasing the price when a product quantity sold is added and decreasing the quantity of the product from the column and database when a product is sold.

I want the quantity of the product inventory to decrease whenever a product is sold by depending on the quantity.

```
double currentPrice = (double)dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value;
double newPrice = currentPrice * 2;
dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = newPrice;

int currentQuantity = (int)dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value;
int newQuantity = currentQuantity - 1;
dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = newQuantity;

string query = "UPDATE tbProduct SET Quantity = " + newQuantity + " WHERE Pid = " + dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
dbcon.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: What is happening that you don't like? Are you getting error messages?

Comment: It looks (on closer reading) like you want to increase the price when the quantity drops. Is that the part that isn't happening?

Comment: When you say "edit a specific column", do you mean "change the value that is displayed" or "allow in-place editing of that cell in that column"?

Comment: @Ann L. Yes I want to increase the price when the quantity of the stocks drop. I am making a petshop management system which involves products and i want to make the price doubled when a customer orders 2 products and triple the price when the customer orders 3 products.... Please help.

Comment: I'm happy to help if I can. Can you tell me what is happening that shouldn't, or should happen that isn't?  It does look as if your query is only updating one column in one table: is that the issue?

Comment: I am a little confused by your code: is the grid showing the products in stock, or the items on the order?

Comment: If it's that you need to make changes in two places, it looks like you're trying to make the grid show the in-stock quantity going _down_ when the customer places an order, and the order price going _up_. Those are (almost certainly) separate tables, and unless the price for the remaining product goes up when the quantity goes down, they may not make sense as part of the same grid.